# Copying desktop installed ubuntu to usb drive with all settings and programs

Tags: installation, usb, cloning

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop/desktop. As a root user, I created 17 other accounts with their own permissions. For example other 17 accounts cannot access to internet, they cannot download or upload anything from usb drives, they all have different username/passwords and also installed my program as a jar file along with some other proprietary documents  onto their home folder. Basically I created their account so that they can only access to my Jar file  and documents nothing else when booted from usb drive.

Now I want to give all those 17 people usb flash drives with the copy of my ubuntu system so that they can each access their own jar files from those usb bootstartup. How should I make copies of my current ubuntu system to usb drives so that I can distribute those jump drives to those 17 peoples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart), or [dd](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Applications_GUI_Multimedia/How_To_Do_Eveything_With_DD), if the installation partition is not too large.

Comment: thanks. will post in future if i encounter any problems with clonezilla.